# Comparison between lz4 vs lz4_hc vs blosc vs snappy vs fastlz

Tags: snappy, lossless-compression, lz4

I have a large file of size 500 mb to compress in a minute with the best possible compression ratio. I have found out these algorithms to be suitable for my use.

1. [lz4](http://lz4.github.io/lz4/)
2. [lz4_hc](http://lz4.github.io/lz4/)
3. [snappy](http://google.github.io/snappy/)
4. [quicklz](http://www.quicklz.com/)
5. [blosc](http://blosc.org/)

Can someone give a comparison of speed and compression ratios between these algorithms?

Comment: Have you found a comparison between lz4 and fastlz?

Comment: I'm interested too, it seems lz4 is more efficient than fastlz but I couldn't find stats proving that fact.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yann Collet's lz4, [hands down](https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/04/13/evaluating-database-compression-methods-update/).

[image]

Comment: What is you recommendation for embedded systems? which is the efficient compression and decompression algorithm regarding and space and time.

Comment: Often people don't know about the large-window brotli and perform large corpus benchmarking with the small-window brotli. Brotli's HTTP content encoding variant is small-window to allow decompression on cheap mobile phones. Other compressors (particularly so lzma and zstd) don't do that limitation and should be compared with large-window brotli, not small-window brotli.

Typically you can see 10 % density improvements (within 0.6 % of lzma) using the large-window brotli, while keeping the high decompression speed.

Answer (score 5):

This migth help you:
(lz4 vs snappy) http://java-performance.info/performance-general-compression/
(benchmarks for lz4, snappy, lz4hc, blosc) https://web.archive.org/web/20170706065303/http://blosc.org:80/synthetic-benchmarks.html
(now not available on http://www.blosc.org/synthetic-benchmarks.html)

Answer (score 2):

If you are only aiming for high compression density, you want to look at LZMA and large-window Brotli. These two algorithms give the best compression density from the widely available open-sourced algorithms. Brotli is slower at compression, but ~5x faster at decompression.

Answer (score 2):

Like most questions, the answer usually ends up being:  It depends :)

The other answers gave you good pointers, but another thing to take into account is RAM usage in both compression and decompression stages, as well as decompression speed in MB/s.

Decompression speed is typically inversely proportional to the compression ratio, so you may think you chose the perfect algorithm to save some bandwidth/disk storage, but then whatever is consuming that data downstream now has to spend much more time, CPU cycles and/or RAM to decompress.  And RAM usage might seem inconsequential, but maybe the downstream system is an embedded/low-voltage system?  Maybe RAM is plentiful, but CPU is limited?  All those things need to be taken into account.

Here's an example of a suite of benchmarks done on various algorithms, taking a lot of these considerations into account:

https://catchchallenger.first-world.info/wiki/Quick_Benchmark:_Gzip_vs_Bzip2_vs_LZMA_vs_XZ_vs_LZ4_vs_LZO

Comment: That was one of the interesting things about H265 vs H264 as well.

H264 encodes faster, but results in a larger size.

H265 results in a smaller result, and the decoder, while more complex, actually runs at similar speeds because the resulting data it needs to work on is significantly less.